# SAS - Use ODS Tagsets and macrovariables to print multiple datasetes to Excel

Tags: sas

I have multiple pre-existing datasets with similar names : EstOut_varname

I am trying to use ODS TAGSETS to output them all to Excel. I am also using a Macro function to loop over the similarly named datasets, like below. However, inside Proc Print, the macrovariable isn't dereferencing the way I thought it would.

Please advice - thanks for any help!

```
ods tagsets.excelxp style=sasweb
file="C:\Users\radhi\Desktop\estvars.xls";
%getBetas;
ods tagsets.excelxp close;


/*** Macro getBetas() to Loop over existing Datsets  that I am trying to output to Excel ***/
/*** The Datasets are all named similarly - EstVar_varname -EstVar_varn1,EstVar_varn2,EstVar_varn3  ***/

%macro getBetas();
%let varnamelist = varn1 varn2 varn3 ;
%put &varnamelist; 
%let end=%sysfunc(countw(&varnamelist));
%put &end;
%do i = 1 %to &end;
    /*** save the varname to macrovariable &out ***/
    %put out= %scan(&varnamelist., &i, " ");
    proc print data=EstVar_&out.;
    run;
%end;
%mend;
```

However, SAS does not dereference EstVar_&out. and does not recognise the &out :

```
proc print data=EstVar_&out.; run;
-
200
ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

---

**NEVER MIND - I just needed to use %LET instead of %PUT inside the the %DO loop in the getBetas macro!**

Comment: Just as an FYI, ODS EXCEL does now exist and will create XLSX files if needed. It's a native XLSX file as well.

Comment: This will  definitely not work in batch as you use the macro before you submit it.  Interactively (in E-Guide) it might work the second time you submit it.

Comment: @Reeza What if I have multiple datasets that each need to output to different Excel sheets in the same Excel file? So, my data is in different datasets - dat1,dat2,...,datN and each of these need to output to their own separate tab in one single Excel. I can't think of a single common BY variable (except perhaps the Row Number). Any suggestions would help!

Comment: The macro is the same, but ODS Excel will generate native XLSX files, ODS TAGSETS generates XML files that Excel can read. Otherwise the code is relatively the same, but your end product is more compatible with current Excel versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `%macro ...; ... %mend;` indeed defines a macro, but that only exists after the code is executed, zo **define** your macro **before** you **use* it.
2. `%put`-statements are handy for debugging, but they don't assign a value to anything. You should use a `%let`-statement to give a macro variable a value.
3. Disclaimer: I never used `ods tagsets`, so I don't guarantee the below code is correct, but at least it handle macro's and macro variables correct.
4. I applied my personal preference for `* ... *;` comments over `/* ... */` comment. Reserving the later for commenting out code allows you to comment out code with comments in it.
5. Why not integrate the `ods` statements in the macro?
6. Why not make the the dataset name prefix, the list of suffixes  and the destination file parameters to `%getBetas`, so it becomes reusable?
7. Disclaimer: I did not test it, so I leave the debugging fun for you.
8. I stop here because you have a lot to learn already, but if it were for me, I would write a macro that prints all datasets with a name matching a `SQL` like condition, which would replace the first two macro parameters.

```
*** Macro getBetas writes similarly named datasets to excel.
    It accepts three parameters:
    - prefix : a common prefix for the dataset names
    - suffixes : a list of suffixes for the dataset names 
    - outFile : the full path of the destination excel file
***;
%macro getBetas(prefix, suffixes, outFile);
  %let suffix_count = %sysfunc(countw(&suffixes));
  %put NOTE: writing &suffix_count datasets 
       starting with &prefix and continuing with one of &suffixes, 
       separated by an underscore 
       to &outFile; 
  ods tagsets.excelxp style=sasweb file="&outFile";
  %do i = 1 %to &suffix_count;
    * save the varname to macrovariable &out *;
    %let out= &prefix._%scan(&suffixes., &i);
    %put NOTE: about to print &out to excel;
    proc print data=&out.;
    run;
  %end;
  ods tagsets.excelxp close;
%mend;

* Printing the similarly named datasets: EstVar_varn1, EstVar_varn2, EstVar_varn3 to excel *;
%getBetas(WORK.EstVar_, varn1 varn2 varn3, C:\Users\radhi\Desktop\estvars.xls);
```